# OpenCL Memory Transfer Issue (Err. code -6)

Tags: opencl, global, nvidia, allocation

I'm dying a little inside. I've been working on this all day to no avail. I was having issues running some code that previously ran fine, so I wrote a short "toy" OpenCL program to try and figure out what was going on, but my toy program has me baffled and incredibly frustrated.

I'm working with an Nvidia 780i with 3Gb of global memory. It has a maximum allocation of ~780 Mb.  At first, it wouldn't error out when I was intentionally over-allocating.  Solved that (it was typographical, but the compiler/analyzer wasn't catching it).  Now, even when trying to allocate WAY below what the device should be able to handle, I get an error code of -6 (CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY) on the second big buffer allocation.

I've been researching this error and I just can't track how it applies in this case.  I have 32 gb of ram in the machine I'm using so there's certainly not a shortage there.  I figure there's something that I just don't understand going on here.

It will allocate the first buffer alright, but then choke on the second.  I basically just cannot allocate nearly the amount of global memory I both want and need to.

Any help is much appreciated. If you can help me with this and you're near LA I'll take you out for drinks.  That's how frustrated I am.

Code and output is below for my machine.

Thanks,
John

Main program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PROGRAM_FILE "kernels.cl"
#define KERNEL_NAME "test"

#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


#define N_PROJ 4000
#define N_CHANNELS 736
#define N_ROWS 32


/* Find a GPU or CPU associated with the first available platform */
cl_device_id create_device() {

    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id dev;
    int err;

    /* Identify a platform */
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    if(err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't identify a platform");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Access a device */
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
    if(err == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
        perror("Just a heads up: I'm not going to run on the GPU");
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
    }
    if(err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't access any devices");
        exit(1);
    }
    cl_ulong16 alloc_size,mem_size;
    char name[40];

    clGetDeviceInfo(dev,CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE,sizeof(cl_ulong16),&alloc_size,NULL);
    clGetDeviceInfo(dev,CL_DEVICE_NAME,sizeof(name),name,NULL);
    clGetDeviceInfo(dev,CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE,sizeof(cl_ulong16),&mem_size,NULL);
    printf("Using device: %s\n",name);
    printf("Global memory size: %lu\n",mem_size);
    printf("Max. allocation: %lu\n",alloc_size);

    return dev;
}

/* Create program from a file and compile it */
cl_program build_program(cl_context ctx, cl_device_id dev, const char* filename) {

   cl_program program;
   FILE *program_handle;
   char *program_buffer, *program_log;
   size_t program_size, log_size;
   int err;

   /* Read program file and place content into buffer */
   program_handle = fopen(filename, "r");
   if(program_handle == NULL) {
      perror("Couldn't find the program file");
      exit(1);
   }
   fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
   program_size = ftell(program_handle)-13;
   rewind(program_handle);
   program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
   program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
   fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);
   fclose(program_handle);

   /* Create program from file */
   program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1,
      (const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
   if(err < 0) {
      perror("Couldn't create the program");
      exit(1);
   }
   free(program_buffer);

   /* Build program */
   err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   if(err < 0) {

      /* Find size of log and print to std output */
      clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            0, NULL, &log_size);
      program_log = (char*) malloc(log_size + 1);
      program_log[log_size] = '\0';
      clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            log_size + 1, program_log, NULL);
      printf("%s\n", program_log);
      free(program_log);
      exit(1);
   }

   return program;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    /* This file serves as a backbone for OpenCL programs. */
    /* All the user needs to do is enter their OpenCL data */
    /* structures, set kernel args, and kernel dispatches. */

    /* Standard OCL structures */
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context context;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_command_queue queue;

    device=create_device();
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    program = build_program(context, device, PROGRAM_FILE);
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device,0, NULL);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, KERNEL_NAME, NULL);

    /* User code goes here */
    cl_int err;

    /* Declare and set data */
    int a[]={1,2,3};
    float *rebin;
    rebin =(float*) calloc(N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS,sizeof(float));
    float *mat;
    mat   =(float*) calloc(N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS,sizeof(float));

    printf("\nAllocation size: %lu\n",N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS*sizeof(float));

    /* Declare and set buffer objects */
    cl_mem a_buff,rebin_buff,mat_buff;

    printf("Total memory to be allocated: %lu\n",2*N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS*sizeof(float)+sizeof(a) );

    a_buff      =clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR|CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(a),a,NULL);
    rebin_buff  =clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR|CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS*sizeof(float),rebin,&err);
    if (err<0){
        printf("Error: %i\n",err);
        perror("Couldn't create buffer 1");
        exit(1);
    }
    mat_buff    =clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR|CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS*sizeof(float),mat  ,&err);
    if (err<0){
        printf("Error: %i\n",err);
        perror("Couldn't create buffer 2");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Copy data over to the device */
    err=clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),&mat_buff);
    if (err<0){
        perror("Couldn't set kernel argument");
        exit(1);
    }
    err=clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem),&rebin_buff);
    err=clSetKernelArg(kernel,2,sizeof(cl_mem),&a_buff);

    clEnqueueTask(queue,kernel,0,NULL,NULL);

    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue,mat_buff  ,CL_TRUE,0,N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS*sizeof(float),mat  ,0,NULL,NULL);
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue,rebin_buff,CL_TRUE,0,N_PROJ*N_CHANNELS*N_ROWS*sizeof(float),rebin,0,NULL,NULL);
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue,a_buff,    CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(a),a,0,NULL,NULL);

    printf("%f %f %f\n",mat[1],mat[2],mat[3]);
    printf("%f %f %f\n",rebin[1],rebin[2],rebin[3]);
    printf("%i %i %i",a[0],a[1],a[2]);

    /***********************/



    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseContext(context);
    //clReleaseDevice(device);

    printf("\n\nProgram apparently executed fully. \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Kernel:

```
    __kernel void test(__global float *mat,__global float *rebin,__global int *a){
    a[0]=3;
    a[1]=2;
    a[2]=1;

    rebin[1]=1.0f;
    rebin[2]=2.0f;
    rebin[3]=3.0f;

    mat[1]=3.0f;
    mat[2]=2.0f;
    mat[3]=1.0f;
}
```

Console output for my machine:

```
Using device: GeForce GTX 780
Global memory size: 3221225472
Max. allocation: 805306368

Allocation size: 376832000
Total memory to be allocated: 753664012
Error: -6
Couldn't create buffer 2: No error

Process returned 1 (0x1)   execution time : 0.435 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Does it work if you make the allocations much smaller? One possible cause would be if this is being built as a 32-bit application, since that would dramatically reduce the amount of host memory you can address.

Comment: I add on top of jprice. That is the maximum you will be able to alloc on the device. But it doesn´t guarantee that the alloc will succeed. 32 bits applications usually only see a fraction of the GPU memory, and can lead to these problems. You should upgrade to 64bits OpenCL.

Comment: Ok, you have buggy application, which gives you a lot of pain. But what is your question exactly?

Comment: I guess, I don't have an incredibly precise question, but had just reached the point where I couldn't see what was going wrong and had exhausted just about everything I knew to do to troubleshoot things (I had spent hours on this before I posted).  I guess my question is "does anyone see anything immediately wrong with the code that I have posted?"

Comment: Also, on the bus ride home after I posted this, I realized that I hadn't been releasing the huge float arrays I was creating.  I think this was probably leaking huge quantities of RAM over the course of the day that I was working on it.  Finally, I am currently linking against a 32 bit library mainly out of convenience (it's what's already installed).  I'll upgrade and try this again.  I didn't think that working with less than four gigs of memory would be an issue with the 32 bit library, but there are a lot of things I don't know!

Comment: Update: I am now using a 64 bit compiler and able to link to the 64 bit libraries with no change.  I've further investigated the upper limits of what I'm able to allocate: two 4187x736x32 arrays of floats when I use the CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR flag in my call to clCreateBuffer(), and two 5584x736x32 arrays of floats when I use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR.  I've made sure to free the memory after use, although that shouldn't make a difference.  I'm still baffled at why I can't allocate a couple of array up the the CL_MAX_ALLOC_SIZE.  That would only use half of the GPU's global memory.

Comment: John H, let's start chat, I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks!  Let me know what info I can offer you.  Not sure if you mean chat outside of stack exchange...